# Style an ActionLink to make it a button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Code", new { id = Model.CodeID }, null)
```

And I'm trying to assign it a class so that I can style it; my attempt so far:

```
<a href="@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Code", new { id = Model.CodeID }, null)"  type="submit" class="button">Delete</a>
```

The result I am getting on my page is:

```
<a href="<a href="/Code/Delete/1">Delete</a>"  type="submit" class="button">Delete</a>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be most helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - *You can apply css class directly to Action link like this*

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Code", new { id = Model.CodeID }, new { @class = "button"} )
```

Answer (score 1):

The last argument is for html attributes. Note that you have to use `@class` instead of `class` as the latter is a reserved word.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Code", new { id = Model.CodeID }, new { @class = "button" })
```